# Give an example of two sets A and B such that |A| = |B|, and a function f : A → B such that f is one-to-one but not onto.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Actually, I am a new student in discrete mathematics and this question appeared in my text book. And just before that I read that if |A|=|B| then the functions A and B must be one-one, onto, Invertible if any one of these is correct for the given functions but now they are saying opposite of this. Can you please explain me this by giving the example?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are **finite** sets, then $|A|=|B|$ if and only if a function from $A$ to $B$ is one-to-one if and only if it’s onto, but if $A$ and $B$ are infinite, this is no longer the case. Pick the simplest infinite set that you know and find a one-to-one function from it to itself that is not onto.

Comment: Yes, I know all of this but it is kinda weird, can you explain this by any kind of example of can give me any like for the work related to that?

Comment: Think about the smallest infinite set you know (as an easy example). Can you construct a function from it to itself such that you "skip" elements (they are never "hit" by the function)?

Comment: Hold on, how do we even know that |A|=|B|. If these are infinite sets?

Comment: I think that example should be just f(x) =2x. Hence it is one-one but not onto

Comment: How about $f(n) = n+1$ on $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: We are looking for one-one but not onto. Is this a correct example, f(x) =2x or 3x or something else?

Comment: Okay, so I concluded that f(x) =x+c where c belongs to positive integers, on N(natural numbers) is one of the examples of the question. If I am somehow wrong. Then please tell me. If I am right then please put the same example or other example in answers. Because I don't know what exactly is going on in chat here. And also in this example|A|=|B| as these are all natural numbers. Right?

Comment: @KaranSingh yes, you've got it right. Feel free to post it as an answer to yourself (and possibly accept your own answer if no other correct, more detailed answer comes along).